# Android: ListView personalizado esta com erro ao simular

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

Implementei um ListView personalizado, básico, mas esta dando o erro:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{goodeal.listview/goodeal.listview.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

Meu Adapter:

```
public class AdapterPropostas extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<Proposta> propostas;
    private final Activity act;

    public AdapterPropostas(List<Proposta> propostas, Activity act) {
        this.propostas = propostas;
        this.act = act;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return propostas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return propostas.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View view = act.getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_linha, viewGroup, false);
        Proposta proposta = propostas.get(i);

        //pegando as referências das Views
        TextView valor = (TextView)
                view.findViewById(R.id.valorProposta);
        TextView qualificacao = (TextView)
                view.findViewById(R.id.qualificacaoCandidato);
        ImageView imagem = (ImageView)
                view.findViewById(R.id.fotoCandidato);


        //populando as Views
        valor.setText(proposta.getValor());
        qualificacao.setText(proposta.getQualificacao());
        imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.para_drawable);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Minha Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdapterPropostas adapter;
    ListView listaDePropostas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Proposta> propostas = todasPropostas();

        listaDePropostas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //chamada da nossa implementação
        adapter = new AdapterPropostas(propostas, this);

        listaDePropostas.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private List<Proposta> todasPropostas(){

        List<Proposta> listaProp = new ArrayList<Proposta>();
        Proposta proposta = new Proposta();
        proposta.setValor("36,21");
        proposta.setQualificacao("5,0");

        listaProp.add(proposta);

        return listaProp;

    }
}
```

Minha ListView:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Minha Linha:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fotoCandidato"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/valorProposta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titulo"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qualificacaoCandidato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="descriçao"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar com esse nullPointer...

Comment: Em que linha dá o erro?

Comment: Onde é que tens o layout `activity_main`? É aquele que está referenciado como "Minha ListView"? É que se a listview não estiver no seu layout `activity_main` quando fizer `listaDePropostas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` ele vai dar null.

Comment: Jorge B. , Obrigado, era isso mesmo. Eu nao sabia que a listView tinha que estar no meu main_layout. Como que eu informo que a sua resposta foi a correta para lhe dar pontos ? nao sei...sou novo aqui...

Comment: Sergio já criei uma resposta, podes marcar como correta. A listview tem de estar no layout da tua atividade, o que fazes `setContentView`.

Comment: Sergio já criei uma resposta, podes marcar como correta (visto ao lado esquerdo da resposta) e votar positivamente (seta para cima). A listview tem de estar no layout da tua atividade, o que fazes `setContentView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde é que tens o layout `activity_main`? É aquele que está referenciado como "Minha ListView"?

É que se a listview não estiver no seu layout `activity_main` quando fizer

```
listaDePropostas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

ele vai dar null. Isto porque a função `findViewById` vai procurar a listView no layout que declaraste no `setContentView` e não a vai encontrar.